# question about asterik in curve fitting code

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, user-defined-functions

In this following example where it is trying to curve fit a sigmoid function to data I don't understand what does * in `*ppot` in line 11 mean

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def sigmoid(x, Beta_1, Beta_2):
     y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Beta_1*(x-Beta_2)))
     return y
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata)
x = np.linspace(1960, 2015, 55)
x = x/max(x)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
y = sigmoid(x, *popt)
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'ro', label='data')
plt.plot(x,y, linewidth=3.0, label='fit')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylabel('GDP')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.show()
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `curve_fit` method returns `popt` as a list of values, in this case, a list of 2 values (optimal values for the parameters).

Adding the `*` before a list splits the list into its values each assigned to a parameter of the function.

Example

```py
>>> # Sample list
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]

>>> # Creating a function that requires 3 parameters
>>> def add(x, y, z):
...     return x + y + z
... 

>>> add(*lst)
6

>>> add(lst)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'
```

Comment: Thank you very much